# Minecraft redstone observers and pistons

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I’m making a 3D printer and the floor rises to push up the blocks. This happens when an observer detects the last row in the grid being pushed into place and it works. The problem comes when the pistons coming back down trigger the observer again, creating an infinite loop. How do I make the observer trigger only once before it gets triggered again?

Comment: 3D printer sounds ambitious.  Any chance we can see a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [stabilizer circuit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Observer_stabilizer).  It is a simple circuit which requires two repeaters and some redstone dust.

Here is an image to build it:

[image: Stabilizer]

**Note**: One of the two repeaters is set to a 4 tick delay.  This solution will pulse the piston twice and then stop.

If you absolutely need the piston to only power once, you have to use a more complicated circuit.  Each cycle the observer pulses 3 times.  Once when a block is placed in front of it, once when the piston extends, and once when the piston retracts.  You have to use a [pulse divider](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pulse_circuit#Pulse_divider) to divide pulses by 3.  This means the circuit will output 1 pulse for every 3 pulses in.  This can be accomplished with 6 droppers, a comparator, a repeater, and some redstone dust.

Here is an image to build it:

[image: Counter]

Place 1 item in the dropper which is being tested by the comparator.  As the observer pulses, the item moves through the dropper system.